# Blocking java UDP DatagramSocket send

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm building a client/server type of application, where the client will be sending millions  of messages. I have a thread whose purpose is only to send packets through a DatagramSocket. The problem is that, right now, the thread is calling the send() method so many types that some packets are being dropped as the internal sending buffer is full.

Is there a way, on java, to have this send() of a DatagramSocket object call block if the buffer is already full, in order to not drop packets?

Comment: You know datagrams do not guarantee delivery anyway?  The U in UDP tells you that.  So pacing on the send side is not necessarily a complete solution.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. Packets are not dropped because the send buffer is full. That causes `DatagramSocket.send()` to *block*. See the Javadoc. Packets are being dropped because UDP can drop them any time it likes anywhere in the network, including the sending host, any intermediate routers, and the receiving host. Either speed up your *receiver* or don't send so fast, or both, or use a reliable protocol with pacing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [DatagramChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html) instead of creating the socket directly.

The channel can be set in blocking mode which, according to the description of [send](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html#send(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.net.SocketAddress)) means the call will wait until buffer space is available.

Comment: Note that this does *not* eliminate the need for you to do transmit pacing to prevent sending data so fast that datagrams are discarded.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Right, There's that "U" in "UDP" again.  Anyone on the way can discard the datagram.  (And that also points up the need for testing across the internet, not just on a single-segment LAN).

Comment: This is not a solution. It doesn't make any difference at all. `DatagramSocket` is already in blocking mode, so it already has exactly the same property. NB 'U' in UDP stands for 'User', not 'Unreliable'. See the RFC.

Comment: Ah, ok. I took the OP's word for the problem being as described.

Comment: The problem with your answer is not the OP's false assumption: it is the complete lack of any difference in this respect between `DatagramSocket.send()` and blocking `DatagramSocketChannel.send()`.